# Search-box: Easy tag browsing

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autocomplete tags in search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/autocomplete-tags-in-search-box)

When I want to search for tags I have to guess the precise tag names. OK, I know the most imporant ones to me, but not the others. It would be nice to have search somehow equipped with this nice autocompletion as it is offered when tagging or retagging a question. This autocompletion is **so** useful! It also shows the popularity of the tags and an explanation of them.

What I do currently is to open a question just to enter words in the tags section to get the tags I want.

Comment: So you're suggesting that the search box in the top use the same tag auto-completion as we get in the tag box when creating a question? Hmm, I like that idea. But I wonder if it should only be triggered when you start by typing a `[` so as not to interfere with standard searches.

Comment: Yes! When autocompletion is performed for tagging or retagging the cursor is usually about in the middle of the screen. And there is still ample of space below to display the matches. When searching, the cursor is close to the top of the screen. So there is even more space below.