# Search for answers using HTML tags within the body

Tags: feature-request, support, search

Often I'll want to link to a previous answer that I know has a screen-shot relevant to a current question.

I was looking over a variety of other questions on Meta mentioned 'search'<sup>1</sup> and the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) on SO to try and ascertain a way to search for `<img` tags in posts (I realize that is not the way that SO normally embeds images, but I reuse them often by forming an `img` element based on the URL of the original).

Is there a way to filter searches for posts containing images?

### 1. Possibly related questions

- [We need to be able to search for punctuation (symbols)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19870/155831)
- [Additional search features/syntax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1114/155831)
- [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/155831)
- [Can we have search default to "AND" instead of "OR"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10713/155831)
- [Autocomplete tags in search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29277/155831)
- [Group search results by question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164396/155831)

Only the first two seem closely related, the first one especially so, but it is referring to specialist symbols such as `===` that would **not** typically be inside an HTML element.

Comment: To be more like [the other search options](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), it would be more like `hasimg:1` or something. I think `<img` should return questions containing that tag instead. Your search query would be `hasimg:1 is:answer some keywords here`

Comment: @Sumurai8  *"Your search query would be hasimg:1 is:answer some keywords here"*  I don't understand.  Are you suggesting that something like that should work currently, or that if implemented, that is how it *should* be implemented?  I tried a couple of variants of hasimg:1 without success.

Comment: If something like this is implemented, the query would look something like that. As the link shows, there is currently no such thing as `hasimg` (or anything image related). There is something as `hascode`, hence why I suggested `hasimg` as the name.

Comment: @Sumurai8  Thanks for clarifying.  I would be happy to see it implemented in any form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given no replies in more than a month, I'm going out on a limb to suggest:

1. No there is no such functionality.
2. Interest in such an ability is so low as to not justify implementing it.