# Auto completion for the search field

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

It would be pretty helpful if the search fields (both quick search and advanced) would feature auto completion of

- tags, once the `[` and the first few letters are entered (maybe even including some typo fixing magic)
- advanced parameters by entering a simple `:` which could then be changed into something like `is:`, followed by sensible suggestions for that, in this example `question`, `closed` etc.

Comment: tag autocompletion has been asked before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/autocomplete-tags-in-search-box

Comment: @rene Thanks, in that case I reduce this to the `:` expansion

Comment: @ShadowWizard I even upvoted that one... thanks

Comment: No worry @Tobias, happens to the best! (myself included, more than once ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually that's nothing, IIRC I once managed to post a dupe of one of my _own_ questions m-/ Though in my defense, it _was_ several years old and had no answers...

Comment: @Tob oh wow, that's a nice one. lol!