# Allow me to search through my bookmarks from my user page, like you can for posts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, search, bookmarks

When you view your user page the search box, right at the top of the page, is updated with your user ID like so:

[image: screenshot showing a user profile and 'user:1075247' in the search box at the top of the page. It features a red freehand circle]

Searching *from this page* (by entering text into the search box) means I can see all of my posts (i.e. questions and answers), because the search box starts with, e.g. `user:1234556`. But there's no equivalent for bookmarks (or tags, I suppose).

There is a way to search for those, as shown in the advanced search guide:

> - `user:mine` or `user:me` (or any user id) returns only your posts (or only the posts from whichever user whose id you entered)
> - `inbookmarks:mine` (or any user id) returns only questions that you (or the user whose id you entered) have bookmarked.
> - `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite. (If you don't have any tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, update your preferences.)

But from here I need to swap out the `user:1075247` for `inbookmarks:1075247`.

May I request *either* changing the term on the bookmarks page to `inbookmarks:1075247` OR allowing for and adding something like `is:bookmark` or `is:b` to switch from all posts to bookmarks.

The same could be done for `is:q`, `is:a`, and `is:tag` for the individual profile pages.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the search term to `inbookmarks:[user id]` or using a shorter search term would be the best option, but I'd also like to add my own suggestion.

---

For each area of the profile page that is searchable (for example, the Answers, Questions and Bookmarks tabs), clicking on the search bar should auto-select the text, after which a user can enter the first letter of the search term resulting in a dropdown list with only the search term(s) relevant for that tab/page.

---

Here's an example of what I mean. Consider the [Bookmarks tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=bookmarks):

1. Clicking on the search bar (when in the Bookmarks tab) would auto-select the text in it:

   [image]

   Note that the Search Help is still preserved.
2. Typing `i` in the search bar would result in a dropdown list:

   > [`i`                                           ]      <— Search bar
   > > inbookmarks:[user id]         ?      <— Dropdown list

   where `user id` can be your own id or someone else's depending on the profile, and `?` is an on-hover/button-click tooltip.
3. Simply <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on that option to switch to a bookmarks search.

So if you use a keyboard to navigate, then that's a total of three keyboard presses. Otherwise, it's only one keyboard press and a click.

---

This seems a bit far-fetched, but I think it's a good idea.

Comment: YES! **I haven't done a full search for previous FRs** but having autocomplete **for tags and search operators** in the search box would be ideal. It would save a lot of typing and copy-pasting every time we do a search. (If anybody finds such previous FRs please link to them in the comments...!)

Comment: @bad_coder: Here's the original FR for the autocomplete feature for tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/autocomplete-tags-in-search-box. I couldn't find one for search operators...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple [userscript](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) that you could use until this functionality is implemented. It works on *all* user profiles (except for the Tags tab, that is limited to your own user ID) - if you visit [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=answers), the search bar will be prepopulated with `user:295232 is:a`.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange, Improved Search From Profile
// @author      Glorfindel
// @version     0.1
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @exclude     *://stackoverflow.com/c/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://winterbash*.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $ */

(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  let search = $("#search input")[0];
  let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  switch (params.get('tab')) {
    case 'answers':
      search.value += ' is:a';
      break;
    case 'bookmarks':
      search.value = search.value.replace('user:', 'inbookmarks:');
      break;
    case 'questions':
      search.value += ' is:q';
      break;
    case 'tags':
      // only works for own tags
      if (search.value == 'user:' + StackExchange.options.user.userId) {
        search.value = 'intags:mine';
      }
      break;
  }
})();
```

Comment: My browser doesn't let me use this because apparently some elements are blocked...!?

Comment: @bad_coder eh ... that surprises me. Do other SE userscripts work for you? Which OS and browser?

Comment: Win 10 + Firefox, just to make sure I'm supposed to copy-paste into web dev tools > console?

Comment: No... here is a guide: https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: Thanks but, I don't like all the overhead that involves plus running 3rd party apps of unknown origin (I could do it on my PC but certainly not on any of my work machines) so that's a no-go for me. I'm sorry but the FR is essentially about having a simpler alias in search, while that makes some users cry *"bloody murder"* it seems like a reasonable FR since search is Q&A "core business" so going 3rd party seems like an unreasonable demand on users.

Comment: I'd be inclined to award the bounty on an answer stating simply: "yes, very desirable feature, shorter aliases could make search much simpler and convenient for the longer terms". Personally I find that kind of support more useful than a userscript that a lot of us (and perhaps most) won't really use.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't think that would qualify as an answer, that's an upvote. Userscripts *are* commonly used by a group of power users; there's even a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19495/295232) about it. But there are lots of reasons not to use them, I can see your point.

Comment: Sadly I can't run userscripts on my machine, but I could save this as a bookmarklet. I'd just have to run it every time I loaded a profile :/

Answer (score 2):

I very much support this FR, you have to type a minimum 12 chars for `inbookmarks:` and unless you're lucky enough to have a user id below `999`  it's a minimum 16 chars to type `inbookmarks:mine` or `inbookmarks:1234`.

Having to type so much to search your bookmarks is especially tedious since it's likely to be a frequent search.

`in:b` or `is:b` seems like the perfect solution.

Comment: Bookmark the `inbookmarks` search result page. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar not a good solution, if I have the page with search open it's better to type in directly. Besides, if the other common operators can be written with minimal chars there's no reason to require 16 chars for the bookmarks, an alias seems very convenient and easy to implement.

Comment: Of course it's very convenient and easy to implement, just such requests usually don't get done, from what I see. They work with a roadmap these days, and don't think improving advanced search is there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar that argument is besides the point of the FR, by your logic no FR should be posted or voted. We also don't know the roadmap or how it will change, (just this week 1 year old FRs were solved I didn't see them on the roadmap).